# Swift - Adding labels to stack views programmatically

Tags: swift, xib, uistackview

My goal is to add labels to a stackview in a xib. Everything below works great if the results are being displayed using a view controller. But I don't need to display the view I'm creating. I just want to add it to an array. (The array will be converted to a PDF later.) For some reason, if I just save the view, anything in the stack view will not appear when the PDF is created. My actual xib has many other fields that show up just fine. It's only the fields I try to programmatically add as labels to a stack view that fail to appear!

This is my xib. The stack view is pinned to the edges and it's set to fill equally.
[image]

And this is the code for the xib. There's one outlet for the view and one for the stack view.

```
import UIKit

class ContainerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testStackView: UIStackView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContainerView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the class that adds labels to the stack view. It has been simplified considerably.

```
import UIKit

class PreparePDF : UIView {

    func addMyArrangedSubviews (
        let containerView = ContainerView()

        let testLabel1 = UILabel()
        testLabel1.text = "Hola"
        testLabel1.backgroundColor = .red

        let testLabel2 = UILabel()
        testLabel2.text = "Hello"
        testLabel2.backgroundColor = .yellow

        containerView.testStackView.addArrangedSubview(testLabel1)
        containerView.testStackView.addArrangedSubview(testLabel2)  

        pdfPages.append(containerView)
}
```

I've tried to ask this question several times, but I think I was making it sound too complicated. I'm not sure this is any better!

Comment: Your call to `loadNibNamed` is not returning anything. From the docs: "You should retain either the returned array or the objects it contains manually to prevent the nib file objects from being released prematurely."

Comment: Okay...let's say that this is the problem. (Which would be great!) I'm still not clear what to change.  Even if I saved the returned array, what would I do with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a view with: `let containerView = ContainerView()`, then you are adding labels to its stackView, then you hit the end of the function and `containerView` is `deinit`ed because you did not retain it or add it as a subview.

Your init for ContainerView is also wrong.  if you call init it will not load the nib file.  You should call `UINib.instantiate(withOwner:options:)` instead and move your setup code to `awakeFromNib` and `fatalError the constructors` so no-one tries to make the nib programmatically and bypass the nib file (in which case the outlets would not be connected).

```
let containerView = UINib(nibName: String(describing: ContainerView.self), bundle: nil)
      .instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! ContainerView
```

Comment: I added the line of code where I save the view - it just goes in an array. But the second half of your answer is interesting. The code I wrote worked fine. The nib file loaded, and I could access its outlets. I just couldn't add anything programatically. So I took your advice and was then able to add labels from code. Kind of. But that's the topic for a different question. Thanks!